# How to clone an object3d in Three.js?

Tags: webgl, three.js

I want to clone a model loaded with loader, I found [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1363) on github,but the solution doesn't work. It seems there has been an structural change in Object3D.

How can I clone an Object3D in current stable version of Three.js?

Answer (score 39):

In this new version of three.js you have a method `clone`.

For example, I use a queen from chess and I had to duplicate multiple times:

```
// queen is a mesh
var newQueen = queen.clone();

// make sure to re position to be able to see the new queen!
newQueen.position.set(100,100,100); // or any other coordinates
```

It will work with any mesh.

I used three.js r61.

Comment: This works, but whenever changing the material property of one of those cloned object3d all of the rest will be affected!

Comment: To avoid sharing the material among all cloned object3d just traverse it as follows: if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) { child.material = child.material.clone(); }

Answer (score 12):

Actually mrdoob's answer is your answer...

The loader output a geometry you use to create a mesh.
You need to create a new mesh with the loader-created mesh's geometry and material.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( loadedMesh.geometry, loadedMesh.material );
    mesh.position.set( i * 100, 0, 0 );
    scene.add( mesh );
}
```

You want to clone a Mesh and not an Object3D because the output of the loader is a Mesh.

Comment: I posted a separate, but similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548280/clone-an-object3d-model-from-a-collada-load-call) since they are related but different as well. Hope you can help.

Comment: this references the same mesh; i.e. if you distort the position of the vertices in the geometry both Meshes are affected

Comment: to allow yourself to mutate the geometry of one without affecting the other, just use `loadedMesh.geometry.clone()` inside the mesh constructor...

Answer (score 5):

**I found one fast solution (not the most efficient)**
 
The [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) uses the [THREE.FileLoader()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/FileLoader) method internally, which allows you to cache files.
To do so, you need to add this line before you create an instance of the [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader)

```
THREE.Cache.enabled = true;
```

Then you can load multiple times the same model, but only the first time will take longer, for example:

```
THREE.Cache.enabled = true;

var loader = new GLTFLoader();

var deeplyClonedModels = [];

for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){

   loader.load('foo.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

     deeplyClonedModels.push(gltf.scene);

  });

}
```