# Clone an Object3D model from a Collada load call

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to clone an ThreeJS Object3D model. I've found various code here and on GitHub and nothing is working for me. The code below comes in part from [How to clone an object3d in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919694/how-to-clone-an-object3d-in-three-js)

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load('../Model.dae', function (result) {
    var loadedMesh = // No sure where this comes from

    // Create X of these
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( loadedMesh.geometry, loadedMesh.material );
        mesh.position.set( i * 100, 0, 0 );
        scene.add( mesh );
    }
}
```

Can you help be fill in the blanks?

Comment: See if this example helps you: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_large_mesh.html

Comment: I had looked at that one before, but it didn't work. Check out what I came up with an the answers.

Comment: @QtBlueWaffle Ask the community in a new post, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load('../Turn.dae', function colladaReady(result) {
    var piece = result.scene.children[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var newPiece = new THREE.Object3D();

        for (var j = 0; j < piece.children.length; j++) {
            newPiece.add(new THREE.Mesh(piece.children[j].geometry, piece.children[j].material));
        }

        newPiece.position.set(i * 100, 0, 0);
        newPiece.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
        scene.add(newPiece);
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

So instead of getting a single mesh, I got a group of meshes. I'm new to this, so I don't know why this is different from what every other answer I've seen. The dae file was exported directly from Sketchup. I'd be interested in knowing if there is a easier/better was to do this.

Comment: I was struggling with this recently too. What was tripping me up was that you have wait until the geometry is truly loaded before you can iterate over it to clone it. That's being taken care of here because the for-loop happens inside of the callback for the loader. Maybe that helps? Thanks for posting your answer!