# Physijs collision events

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs

I have two boxes. One spawns on the ground and the other is dropped on top of it. Gravity is turned on. I am trying to get the collision event listener to fire on the bottom box which is resting on the ground. However, nothing is logged.

```
var c = new Physijs.BoxMesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5, 5, 5 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x888888 }) );
c.__dirtyPosition = true;
c.position.set(10, 0,-5);

c.addEventListener('collision', function(object){
    console.log("hello world"); // NOT FIRING
});

scene.add(c);

var p = c.clone();
p.__dirtyPosition = true;
p.position.y = 50;
scene.add(p);
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - could it be because of `__dirtyPosition`?

EDIT: I tested it without `clone()` and creating the second box anew, but it doesn't make a difference.

EDIT 2: It's worth mentioning that the simulation runs fine I just can't get the listener to work.

Comment: try setting __dirtyPosition *after* position.y has changed

Comment: @Neil thanks but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

*[Relevant GitHub Issue](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/issues/178)*

It looks like the `clone` method is [part of THREEjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19729589/2006429), not Physijs. So your code just clones the physical **material**, not the physical **mesh**. You're just going to have to create another `BoxMesh` using the same code you did for `c`.

Comment: Actually, this code works fine outside of the scope of my application, the problem was something specifically inside the rest of my code.