# Function that clones a group of objects in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, object, three.js

I am trying to create a scene for my class where a group of objects (a model) has to be cloned and displayed in random positions. I created a function for this, but unfortunately, it only transfers the same object from one place to another. I need to add more objects instead of moving the same one, but sadly I cannot find any information about it. I tried to clone, but I failed :/ Later on, I will have to remove these models one by one, so if anybody could give advice on that too, I would appreciate it.

Here's my code:

```
this.addmodel = function() {
    scene.add(model);
    model.name = "model-" + scene.children.length;
    model.position.x= -20 + Math.round((Math.random() * 40));
    model.position.y= Math.round((Math.random() * 5));
    model.position.z= -17.5 + Math.round((Math.random() * 35));
    this.numOfObjects = scene.children.length;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone an object3d in Three.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919694/how-to-clone-an-object3d-in-three-js)

Answer (score 1):

Sample object:

```
function Model(){
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"red"}));
  this.addModel = function(){
    var newModel = this.mesh.clone();
    newModel.name = "model-" + scene.children.length;
    newModel.position.x= -20 + Math.round((Math.random() * 40));
    newModel.position.y= Math.round((Math.random() * 5));
    newModel.position.z= -17.5 + Math.round((Math.random() * 35));
    scene.add(newModel);
  }
};
```

then create an instance and call its method:

```
  var cubeModel = new Model();
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cubeModel.addModel();
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/138tgLjh/) example

Comment: I think I did not make myself clear. I have a group of objects grouped into a var model = new THREE.Object3D(); And I need to recreate that group of objects (the "model") one after another with a function (when a person clicks on a button, new "model" appears in the screen in a random position :)

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle. Cloning of a group of objects grouped into a THREE.Object3D() also works.